# Pandas: population new columns from other column's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a pandas.dataframe of SEC reports for multiple tickers & periods.

Reproducible dict for DF:

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
 'field': {0: 'taxonomyid',
  1: 'cik',
  2: 'companyname',
  3: 'entityid',
  4: 'primaryexchange'},
 'value': {0: '50',
  1: '0000023217',
  2: 'CONAGRA BRANDS INC.',
  3: '6976',
  4: 'NYSE'},
 'ticker': {0: 'CAG', 1: 'CAG', 2: 'CAG', 3: 'CAG', 4: 'CAG'},
 'cik': {0: 23217, 1: 23217, 2: 23217, 3: 23217, 4: 23217},
 'dcn': {0: '0000023217-18-000009',
  1: '0000023217-18-000009',
  2: '0000023217-18-000009',
  3: '0000023217-18-000009',
  4: '0000023217-18-000009'},
 'fiscalyear': {0: 2019, 1: 2019, 2: 2019, 3: 2019, 4: 2019},
 'fiscalquarter': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'receiveddate': {0: '10/2/2018',
  1: '10/2/2018',
  2: '10/2/2018',
  3: '10/2/2018',
  4: '10/2/2018'},
 'periodenddate': {0: '8/26/2018',
  1: '8/26/2018',
  2: '8/26/2018',
  3: '8/26/2018',
  4: '8/26/2018'}}
```

The column 'field' contains the name of the reporting field (e.g. Indicator), column 'value' contains value for that indicator. Other columns are description for the SEC filing (ticker+date+fiscal_periods = unique set of features to describe certain filing). There are about 60-70 indicators per filing (number varies).

With the code below I've managed to create a pivot dataframe with columns = features (let say total number of N for 1 submission). But the length of this dataframe also equals the number of indicators = N, with NaN in non-diagonal places.

```
# Adf - Initial dataframe
c = Adf.pivot(columns='field', values='value')
d = Adf[['ticker','cik','fiscalyear','fiscalquarter','dcn','receiveddate','periodenddate']]
e = pd.concat([d, c], sort=False, axis=1)
```

I want to use an Indicator names from the 'field' as new columns (going from narrow to wide format). At the end I want to have a dataframe with 1 row for each of SEC reports. 
So the expected output for provided example is a 1-row dataframe with N new columns, where N = number of unique indicators from the 'field' column of initial dataframe:

```
{'ticker': {0: 'CAG'},
 'cik': {0: 23217},
 'dcn': {0: '0000023217-18-000009'},
 'fiscalyear': {0: 2019},
 'fiscalquarter': {0: 1},
 'receiveddate': {0: '10/2/2018'},
 'periodenddate': {0: '8/26/2018'},
 'taxonomyid':{0:'50'},
 'cik': {0: '0000023217}',
 'companyname':{0: 'CONAGRA BRANDS INC.'},
 'entityid':{0:'6976'},
 'primaryexchange': {0:'NYSE'},
```

}

What is the proper way to create such columns from or what is the proper way to clean-up resulting dataframe from multiple NaN?

Comment: what is your expected out put

Comment: Thanks for noting - edited the original post. The expected output for provided example is a 1-row dataframe with N new columns, where N = number of unique indicators from the 'field' column of initial dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is setting new index to DF and unstacking 'field' and 'value' columns

```
aa = Adf.set_index(['ticker','cik', 'fiscalyear','fiscalquarter',  'dcn','receiveddate', 'periodenddate', 'field']).unstack()
aa = aa.reset_index()
```